# Gradle Sync Failure

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have updated my build tools as well as the individual libraries to version 23. Initially it failed to sync because i didnt have API 23 installed. But even after i did, the same error occurs. [image]

This is how my build.gradle file looks like

[image]

Why wont it build?

This is the error I am receiving.
[image]

Comment: @Gatunox check edited question

Comment: have you clean the proyect form the menu?

Comment: Click on the "Install missing platform(s) and sync project" link in the error message. It probably wants the platform sources or something like that.

Comment: Cleaning the project has worked actually.

Comment: You are welcome....:(